# Linux watchdog and NTP

Tags: linux, ntp, watchdog

I am using an ARM embedded device but I think this is a general Linux question.

I'm using the Linux watchdog daemon with the 'file' option to periodically check my application changes the time every xx seconds or so. This works fine but I've noticed if the system time is way off and NTP updates the time then the watchdog reboots. Presumably it has a hissy fit noticing that the stat on the file has changed a lot (the time was several months in the past so jumped ahead in time when corrected).

I can't disable the watchdog because I have the NOWAYOUT option enabled and I have the 'tinker panic 0' option enabled for NTP because it's an embedded device that may not be connected to a network for long periods or be powered off for longer than the RTC backup can last.

I think the device reboots at the instant my application calls 'utime' to modify the file. I'm not sure if this is just before or after NTP does its stuff. On a couple of devices the time doesn't seem to get permanently changed as it reboots due to the watchdog and repeats indefinitely. I thought one of the actions the watchdog performed before a reboot was to update the hardware time?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem. Because i'm encountering the same thing. I've been thinking about running a script that checks for NTP connection before starting the watchdog daemon... But i was wondering if there was a less hacky solution.

Comment: No sorry I can't remember how I left this, but I assume we just lived with the fact that a change in time would cause a reboot. I'm wondering whether the same thing happens with a change due to daylight savings.

Comment: Okay, no problem. I've "fixed" it now with a test-binary, which first checks for NTP connection and if the time has synced. Then I check the file with a self implemented "file" option. Not the prettiest solution, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a huge weakness of the watchdog service. Whenever the OS time is updated by an amount that exceeds the file check interval, the file check fails, and the system gets rebooted.

What I did was abandon the `file=` check, and used `test-binary=` instead. This way, the watchdog executes a script, and the script uses the monotonic clock instead of the wall clock to check the file for changes.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the watchdog daemon shouldn't be updating the system time ever, and that would include prior to causing the system to reboot. The watchdog daemon isn't what actually ***causes*** the reboot, the system hardware does that when the watchdog isn't "petted".

Getting a watchdog to function properly requires that you understand how your device's hardware works, and how the daemon which will be "petting" the watchdog makes the "pet" or "don't pet" decision.

You've not provided enough information for me to look at either your embedded device's documentation, or the source code for the daemon itself. My suggestion would be for you to do "whatever you can" to cause NTP to set the system time prior to the watchdog having an opportunity to time out. I'd also suggest you look at the package information for the watchdog version you're using and report this as a bug to the maintainer. Just as the hardware watchdog isn't affected by changes to the system time, the software watchdog shouldn't either. Current system uptime *is* available and I'd expect the software watchdog -- the daemon -- to be able to handle changes with the wall-clock time without rebooting the system.